# SQL: ISNULL function with different type of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, isnull

In SQL Server, [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) function has to same type of parameters.

> check_expression
>
> Is the expression to be checked for NULL. check_expression can be of
>   any type.
>
> replacement_value
>
> Is the expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL.
>   replacement_value **must have the same type as check_expresssion**.

How can I use it with different type of parameter? I want to use with `date` and `string` parameter like this `ISNULL(A.DATE, '-')`

**NOTE**: Type of `A.DATE` is `datetime`.

**EDIT-1**: My full query which is getting 0 row:

```
    SELECT A.pkey as KREDİ, A.SUMMARY , D.BayiStatu AS STATU, D.Sorumlu AS SORUMLU, C.BayiSonuc as SONUC, ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.CREATED, 112) , '-' ), ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.RESOLUTIONDATE, 112) , '-' ), dbo.CUSTVAL(11931, A.ID, 'S') AS BAYİ, ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), dbo.GetLastStatuTime(A.ID), 112) , '-' ) AS SON_STATU_TAR,j2.SUMMARY, ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), j2.CREATED, 112) , '-' ), ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), j2.RESOLUTIONDATE, 112) , '-' ), j3.SUMMARY, ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), j3.CREATED, 112) , '-' ), ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), j3.RESOLUTIONDATE, 112) , '-' )
FROM AspNetServicesDB.dbo.SONUC_MAP C, JİRA.resolution E, jira.issuestatus B, AspNetServicesDB.dbo.STATU_MAP D, Jira.jiraissue A
INNER JOIN Jira.issuelink i
    ON i.SOURCE = A.ID and i.SEQUENCE = 0
INNER JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j2
    ON i.DESTINATION =j2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Jira.issuelink i2 
    ON i2.SOURCE = A.ID  and i2.SEQUENCE = 1
LEFT JOIN Jira.jiraissue As j3 
    ON i2.DESTINATION = j3.ID
WHERE A.issuestatus = B.ID
AND 'BAŞARAN OTOMATİV' = dbo.CUSTVAL(11931, A.ID, 'S')
AND B.pname = D.JiraStatu collate Turkish_CS_AI
AND A.issuetype != 11
AND A.RESOLUTION = E.ID
AND E.pname = C.JiraSonuc collate Turkish_CS_AI
```

**EDIT-2**: But this working

```
select ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.RESOLUTIONDATE, 112) , '-' )
FROM Jira.jiraissue A
```

Could be the reason `JOIN` ?

Comment: If `select ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.RESOLUTIONDATE, 112) , '-' )` works then this `ISNULL(A.DATE, '-')` problem is _solved_. Now, you have another problem. This means another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The ISNULL function is used by itself as a query result column, or in an expression that eventually is a column in the query result. All fields/rows in a column must have the same data type. So you'll have to choose.

One solution would be to cast the DATE to string, so the result is always a string, but i feel the *best* solution would be to return NULL for empty dates and let the presentation layer decide whether or not the NULL dates should be shown as `-` and in what format the non-null dates should be displayed (client locale settings).

With presentation layer, I mean anything that displays or outputs this data, which can be a web page, a CSV exporter, a reporting tool, whatever.

Comment: I use in Gridview and It's dateformatstring is {0:f}. How can I do in with Gridview for checking is null or not?

Comment: I'm not much of a .NET guy, but I think you should be able to specify a column formatting, or maybe even an even to do the formatting somewhere. Can't be sure though, never done anything with this GridView, but I would be surprised if this wasn't easy to do.

Comment: Did you mean to say "IFNULL" when the question is about `ISNULL()`?

Comment: Changed it. I meant that one function that replaces a NULL value with another value, which is called IFNULL, ISNULL, NVL or maybe other names, depending on the database. ;)

Comment: Yes, and NVL is Oracle. But they are essentially the same function. I just made a typo.

Comment: I feel stupid myself, why can't I solve this easy problem. `ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), A.Date, 101),'-')` why this is not working still don't understand.

Comment: @SonerGönül - Did you tested ISNULL(...) solution in SSMS ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Yep. ISNULL doesn't work because of different type of parameters. After that, I use CONVERT like `ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), A.Date, 101),'-')` but still getting 0 rows. I almost kill myself :-)

Comment: I solved it. This is the oldest true answer an I accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Can you simply cast your date as a varchar? Since you're output may not be a valid date anyway, this should work just fine:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10), A.Date, 101),'-')
```

Comment: @SonerGönül: Are you using this expression as a filter (somewhere in `WHERE` or `ON`)?

Comment: @AndriyM I added full query in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the date to a string if you really want a `-` instead of `null`.

```
declare @T table(adate datetime)
insert into @T values(null)
insert into @T values(getdate())

select isnull(convert(varchar(23), adate, 126), '-')
from @T
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 CASE WHEN A.DATE IS NULL
      THEN '-'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), A.DATE, 112)
 END
```