# When using ISNULL, you can potentially return 2 different types

Tags: sql-server, isnull

Given the following example:

```
declare @t1 AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @t1 = 'asdf'

SELECT ISNULL(@t1, 0) AS test1
```

Now if @t1 was NULL, the call to ISNULL would return 0 which is an INT.

So this means you have 2 potential data types being return for the same column correct?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: You can use COALESCE for different behavior. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to learn, this post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963652/sql-isnull-function-with-different-type-of-parameters

Comment: Read the section on return types in the documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine Sql server does am implicit Conversion and converts 0 into string '0' because of the datatype of the column being returned.

```
DECLARE @Test_TABLE TABLE(Column1 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Test_TABLE VALUES
('ALPHA'),(NULL),('Beta'),('Gemma')

SELECT ISNULL(Column1, 0)
FROM @Test_TABLE
```

This will throw an error as when sql server tries to convert to the datatype of the column which is INT it fails and it throws an error

```
DECLARE @Test_TABLE1 TABLE(Column1 INT)
INSERT INTO @Test_TABLE1 VALUES
(1),(NULL),(2),(3)

SELECT ISNULL(Column1, 'Is null')
FROM @Test_TABLE1
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'Is null' to data type int.

Your can see one datatype takes precedence on other and only One data type is returned not two :)